# how to execute code after the exception in scala using Try

Tags: scala, akka, future, futuretask, akka-actor

i have two actors they can either return the Result which is a boolean value in my case or they can throw an exception here is my code

```
val futureA: Future[Boolean] = ask(ActorA, MessageA(obj)).mapTo[Boolean]
val resultA = Await.result(futureA, timeout.duration) //can return boolean or throw an exception 

val futureB: Future[Boolean] = ask(ActorB, MessageB(obj)).mapTo[Boolean]
       val resultb = Await.result(futureB, timeout.duration)//can return boolean or throw an exception
```

Here i want to achieve
**scenario-1** if futureA and FutureB Succeed i should get something like  (futureResponseA,futureResponseB) //(true, true)

**scenario-2** if futureA fails it should proceed with FutureB if it return successfully i should get something like (exceptionOfFutureA,resultofFutureB)

**scenario-3** if futureA return successfully and futureB fails i should get something like (futureResponseA,exceptionOfFutureB)

**scenario-4** if futureA and futureB both failed i should get something like (exceptionOfFutureA,exceptionOfFutureB)

for that i tried with 
      val futureA = ask(ActorA, MessageA(obj)).mapTo[Boolean]
      val futureB = ask(ActorB, MessageB(obj)).mapTo[Boolean]

```
  val f = Try {Future.sequence(List(futureA, futureB))}
  val result = Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
```

but i am getting error on this `val result` line

```
found   : scala.util.Try[scala.concurrent.Future[List[Boolean]]]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Awaitable[?]
```

How can i archive these scanerios please guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Try` isn't an `Awaitable`, and a `Future` won't throw an exception, but the `Await` can. So you need to wrap the `Await` with a `Try` and, since you want to capture either or both failures, that means 2 different `Await`s.

```
val resultTuple = (Try(Await.result(futureA, Duration.Inf))
                  ,Try(Await.result(futureB, Duration.Inf)))
```

The result type is `Tuple2[Try[Boolean],Try[Boolean]]`, which covers the 4 scenarios you laid out: (Success,Success) (Success,Failure) (Failure,Success) (Failure,Failure)